# Swift extending Array of specific type

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, dictionary, extension-methods

I'm trying to extend arrays that have dictionaries as it's elements, where the dictionaries' values are comparable. It's basically like an array of custom objects and sorting them by specific property values, only in this case, it's dictionaries, not class instances.

One could see the data structure as `Array<Dictionary<Key: Hashable, Value: Comparable>>`, although the previous code is unsupported..

I think it comes close to working, but fails for various reasons.

My first attempts were

```
extension ArrayLiteralConvertible where Element == Dictionary<String, Comparable> {
    func sortByKey<T: Comparable>(key: String, ascending: Bool) -> [[String: T]]? {
        if let dictType = self as? [[String: T]] {
            return ascending ? dictType.sort { return $0[key] < $1[key] } : dictType.sort { return $0[key] > $1[key] }
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

This works in the declaration, but when in use, it throws the error

> Dictionary is not convertible to '[String: Int]'

Another attempt:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == [String: AnyObject] {
    func sortByKey<T: Comparable>(key: String, ascending: Bool) -> [[String: T]]? {
        if let dictType = self as? [[String: T]] {
            return ascending ? dictType.sort { return $0[key] < $1[key] } : dictType.sort { return $0[key] > $1[key] }
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

gives back

> Argument type "[[String: _]]?" does not conform to expected type 'Any' (aka 'protocol<>')

How could I make this work?

**ADDED**

I made-do with the following, but it's constrained to a specific type, so I have to declare separately for other types like String..

```
extension ArrayLiteralConvertible where Element == [String: Int] {
    func sortByKey(key: String, ascending: Bool) -> [[String: Int]] {
        let arraySelf = self as! [[String: Int]]
        return ascending ? arraySelf.sort { return $0[key] < $1[key] } : arraySelf.sort { return $0[key] > $1[key] }
    }
}
```

Another alternative:

```
func sortArray<T: Comparable>(array: [[String: T]], byKey key: String, ascending: Bool) -> [[String: T]] {
    return ascending ? array.sort { return $0[key] < $1[key] } : array.sort { return $0[key] > $1[key] }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you did pretty well. I don't know if you'll like this any better:

```
func sortedArrayOfDictionaries<T:Comparable>(arr:[[NSObject:T]], byKey key:NSObject) -> [[NSObject:T]] {
    return arr.sort({ (d1, d2) -> Bool in
        return d1[key] < d2[key]
    })
}
```

To use it, you must cast your initial array so that the key is of type NSObject:

```
let arr : [[NSObject:Int]] = [["hey":2], ["hey":1]]
let arr2 = sortedArrayOfDictionaries(arr, byKey: "hey")
```

I arrived at that independently, but on inspection it's not significantly different from your second solution. The only difference, really, is that we are not restricted to a string key.